# Need Alphanumeric Regex

Tags: jquery

My text box accept alphanumeric and on submit button click I need to make sure that textbox contains should at least 1 char (a-z|A-Z) and 1 digit (0-9).

Please help me in regex pattern.

Comment: Can you provide examples to valid inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/`  Should be what you need

### edit

Here's one that takes either alpha->numeric or numeric->alpha:

`([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)`

Note that you need to `match_all` because this will match each group of `letter-number` and `number-letter` as individual matches.

Comment: This pattern requires the input to contain a letter that is followed by a number.

Comment: Your edit still requires that there cannot be any other characters between the letter and numbers.

Comment: @Ates yes, he said his textbox should accept alphanumeric.  This is alphanumeric.

Comment: Ah! Missed the "alphanumeric" detail. +1